# PHP: IF statement or either the mysql_query won't work

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a strong feeling that the IF or mysql_query won't work.
(I guess it is the IF)

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']) && $admin == "3"){
        $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM dis_posts WHERE post_id = '".$posts['post_id']."'");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        header("Location: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
```

Help please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpfull to know what DOES and what SHOULD happen.

Comment: You're calling `mysql_query()` _twice_. First with the sql string (correctly) and immediately after with the boolean it returned (incorrect)

Comment: It should delete the row inside the "dis_posts" table, row: "post_id".

Comment: Please see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and begin learning about prepared statements in PDO or MySQLi.  The `mysql_*()` extension is deprecated in PHP 5.5 and should not be used for new code.

Comment: Have you tried printing the contents of the POST variable and $admin variable to make sure they contain what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If your database connection is alright then
**Try Like this:**

```
   if(isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($admin) && $admin == "3"){
            $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM dis_posts WHERE post_id = '".$posts['post_id']."'");
         if(!$query){

           echo "could not updated!";
         }else {
            header("Location: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
         }
   }
```

Comment: @Billy_2lgit_2qt: Did you try this? another thing is that $posts['post_id'] or  $_POST['post_id'] ?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it seems like maybe this is what you are trying to do...

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']) && $admin == "3"){
    $query = "DELETE FROM dis_posts WHERE post_id = '".$posts['post_id']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result){
        header("Location: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry... didn't see Awlad's post until my screen refreshed.  Same concept with the addition of the "echo" statement for some visual feedback.